# How do i create Pin Wheel(Like Daisy Wheel) in iPhone

Tags: animation, ios4

I want to create a pin wheel(Like msnbc apps). Please see the below image. How do i create a pin wheel. Is there any sample code or tutorials available?.please guide me to how to achieve this?.

[Sample Image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e11f35e522.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e11f35e522.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need basic images, you can create it then load it in a UIImageView like so: (assuming you defined and init it)

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR-Image-File.png"];
```

If you want them to rotate, make sure the centre of each image is the point where you want to rotate from.

This may not be the best method if you are looking for special effect, but it should work for a basic pin wheel.